# Using OleDBCommand to insert data into an Access database, but table shows -1 as the result

Tags: vb.net, oledb

With the following code, I'm simply trying to take the value of a textbox (txtResult.Text) and insert that value into an Access database table. The code runs without error, except that the value that populates into the table is -1 instead of the expected string value (ex. 5+5=10). Any help??

```
Dim con As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Marcus\Desktop\ENTD461Week6.accdb")
Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand
Dim var1 As String
con.Open()
cmd.Connection = con

Try

    listOperations.Add(txtResult.Text)
    listNumber1.Add(Val(txtNo1.Text))
    listNumber2.Add(Val(txtNo2.Text))

    var1 = txtResult.Text               
    cmd.CommandText = ("INSERT into tblExpressions (Expressions) VALUES(" + var1 + ")")
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()          

Catch ex As Exception

    MsgBox(ex.Message)

End Try
```

Comment: If you expect to insert string value then that's what you have to insert, which you are not.  Just as string literals in VB are denoted by double-quotes, strings in SQL are denoted by single-quotes.  Without them, your text is being interpreted as an arithmetic expression and logical expression, i.e. it is adding 5 and 5 and comparing the result to 0 for equality and coming up with `False`, which is -1 as a number.

Comment: Thank you so very much! The quotes worked.

Comment: In the title, I changed the example expression, "5+5=0" to "5+5=10" because that's what I originally meant.

Comment: 5 + 5 = 10 is `true` because the sum of five and five *is* ten, and the numeric equivalent of `true` is -1 (in this case, in other languages it could be 1). `False` would be 0.

Comment: Indeed, I now understand that the reason I was getting -1 was that because I didn't surround the "var1" variable in single quotes, the .Net command object was looking at it as an actual expression to evaluate instead of a string literal. Thanks!